# Cordova not using css and js when built on device

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I'm making an app that consists of an html file using Cordova. However, when I build my app, it doesn't include either CSS or want to use JS.

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
        function showDiv() {
           document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
        }
        </script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <title>InstaPlan</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
        <div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>
        <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
          <h1 id="sub">Onsdag 20/4 Uke 16:</h1>
          <h1 id="mid">
             <small>Gym MatteNorsk</small>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
          <h1 id="mid"><small>Lekser til Torsdag:</small></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
          <h1 id="sub">ayylmao ingen lekser</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

I'm using CSS from a separate file which is located within the WWW folder just like the index.html, and I'm also using some CSS from bootstrap. I don't know if that will affect it. However, the javascript that is in the header tag doesn't seem to run either. It doesn't want to display the div. Is this caused by CSS not working, seeing that it's using style.display?

Thank you

Comment: could you download the bootstrap.min.css locally to the project folder and try once to narrow down the issue?

Answer (score 1):

i was suffering from the same problem by puting the script in the head and call the function in an HTML element as you did and once i changed the script to the bottom of the page like this

```
...
<div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
          <h1 id="sub">ayylmao ingen lekser</h1>
        </div>
        <script>
        function showDiv() {
           document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
        }
        </script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

otherwise the script will be interpreted after the DOM was downloaded !!

Comment: I tried this, but it still won't work :/ btw sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1):

Make sure if where the css file and index file are located

as you call the css in the file is **wrong**

**<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">**

if your index file and css file are in same folder

`www/index.html` & `www/main.css`

Then wrote the link like

**<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">**

or if the css file in in inner folder of style or any other than

**<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">**

And this will work for you

## Updated

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>InstaPlan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
    <div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >WELCOME</div>
    <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
        <h1 id="sub">Onsdag 20/4 Uke 16:</h1>
        <h1 id="mid">
            <small>Gym MatteNorsk</small>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron" id="nbn">
        <h1 id="mid"><small>Lekser til Torsdag:</small></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron" id="nbm">
        <h1 id="sub">ayylmao ingen lekser</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Created folder for style in www folder**

**style/main.css**

```
.jumbotron h1{
   font-size: 12px;
   text-decoration: underline;
   font-weight: 200;
}
```

**Created folder for js in www folder**

**js/main.js**

```
function showDiv() 
{
    document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

It's working for me with the bootstrap css and mine custom css

please try this and let me know if this is works for you or not.

Comment: The reason I changed to that was because it was suggested in another thread, but it didn't do anything. Changing it back still didn't do anything :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by the cordova-whitelist issue. Please refer to cordova-whitelist plugin for including external css files.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: So I tried to add bootstrap to the whitelist, but I got this comment during the build. 

Updating plugins based on manifest.json
## Running Cordova Command: plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0" via npm
Plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" already installed on android.

and when I ran the build on my phone, it didn't show the CSS :/

Comment: The problem might be with your Content Security Policy meta tag in the head in index.html - can you post that.

Comment: In the Index.html that I've posted in the original post? Or in the whitelist that I downloaded?